# Bind fullscreen app for specific Desktop

Tags: spaces, mission-control, fullscreen

Is it possible to bind an app to Desktop? For instance, I want to have Safari app in **fullscreen mode** on Desktop 2, but when I enter to fullscreen mode, Safari creates it's own space. My eventual goal is to have an ability to switch between spaces with command+desktop_number shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, for fullscreen.
Fullscreen apps don't have a Space/Desktop number. They are "to the right" of any numbered Spaces, & the order, as far as I've ever been able to discern, is 'random' [order created].

Your workaround is to maximise the window [hover the cursor in a window corner then when you see it change to a double diagonal arrow, double-click], rather than fullscreen it. Then you can lock it to a numbered Space.